# Can't change PHP version to 7.4.27 from 7.1.3 in Easyphp Devserver 17

Tags: php-7.4, easyphp, easyphp-devserver

I installed the PHP 7.4.27 version in Easyphp Devserver 17 on my local PC.
In the Easyphp dashboard the PHP 7.4.27 version correctly appears in the list of the PHP versions installed but it does not appear in the list when I try to change from current PHP 7.1.3 version to the installed PHP 7.4.27 version.

Here a screenshot of my Easyphp dashboard as I try to perform the change.

[image: Attempt to change PHP version]

I tried to change manually the httpd-php.conf replacing the current PHP path with the PHP 7.4.27 path whenever it occurs but as I restart the Easyphp server it overwrites the file and restore the PHP 7.1.3 path.

I didn't have this issue when installing PHP 8.1.0 as you can see from the screenshot, it appears both in the list of available PHP version and in the menu when I attempt to change the PHP version.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that the reason for not being able to select 7.4.27 PHP version was that I actually installed the x64 version instead of the x86 version. I did not receive any error during installation, the PHP version was correctly listed but it did not allowed to select it as the current version. Once I installed the x86 version everything worked flawlessly. So the issue is solved.